# How do I create a 'urlpattern' with an indefinite amount of 'named regex groups'

Tags: python, django, django-views

### Explanation

I want to have a folder type structure with my website urls, like this example:

```
www.sitename.com/catagory/sub-catagory/another-catagory/yet-another
```

currently inside my urls.py I have the following `urlpattern` to begin to describe this:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-\/]+)/', views.page_view)
```

---

### My Problem

The url seems to only get the last part of the url, so if I entered the following

```
www.sitename.com/catagory/sub-catagory/another-catagory/yet-another
```

it only seems to capture

```
yet-another
```

I've got no idea how to fix this, any help would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work correctly

```
# urls.py 
url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-\/]+)/', views.page_view)

# views.py
def page_view(request, slug):
    slug  #
```

For a url `www.example.com/a/b/c/d` it'll capture `a/b/c` which can be split at `/`.

For a url `www.example.com/a/b/c/d/` it'll capture `a/b/c/d`

Comment: Isn't that the same as mine? Am I missing something here, I feel really silly. It doesn't seem to be working for me, still getting the same result as mentioned in the initial post :(

Comment: Yes it's the same one, I plugged it in, it works (Django 1.8)

Comment: I just realized my problem! The links I were using were incorrect... I knew I was doing something stupid here... I'm so sorry for wasting your time Ken! :(

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.